# Maven Shade and Clover won't work for mvn site

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-shade-plugin, clover

I have parent project and some child projects. Some of the child have dependency between each other. eg: parent - > child 1, parent -> child 2, child 1 -> child 2(Child1 is dependent on child 2)
Here is what I am doing in my poms:

```
  <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
  </plugin>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <jdk>${compile.source}</jdk>
      <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
      <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
      <generateXml>true</generateXml>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>pre-site</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>instrument</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <reportPlugins>
              <plugin>
          <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clover2-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.10.1</version>
          <configuration>
            <jdk>${compile.source}</jdk>
            <generateHtml>true</generateHtml>
            <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
            <generateXml>true</generateXml>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </reportPlugins>
```

Child pom looks something like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
      <filters>
        <filter>
          <artifact>*:*</artifact>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
            <exclude>META-INF/LICENSE</exclude>
            <exclude>config.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </filter>
      </filters>
      <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <mainClass>com.cerner.pophealth.program.runtime.pipeline.Main</mainClass>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I am facing issue where mvm site-deploy would fail with following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:1.7.1:shade (default) on project foo: Error creating shaded jar: error in opening zip file /foo/bar/target/classes -> [Help 1]
```

mvn site-deploy is run from foo-parent level.

I have noticed even when site is run clover tries to create shaded jar within target/clover/ folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used profile to enable/disable shaded plugin.

```
   <profiles>
<profile>
  <id>shade</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

The maven-clover2-plugin has two goals which can be used for source code instrumentation:

The **clover2:instrument** goal forks a parallel build life cycle in Maven in order to instrument sources. Which means that source roots (like *src/main/java* and *src/test/java*) as well as output folders (like *target/classes*) are being redirected to the *target/clover* directory. Such folder redirection may indeed in some cases cause trouble for other Maven plugins running.

The **clover2:setup** goal performs code instrumentation in Maven's default build life cycle. Which means that output folders remain unchanged (and instrumented classes are put into *target/classes*, for instance).

I suggest to try the clover2:setup instead goal of the clover2:instrument one. However, please keep in mind that calling the 'clover2:setup' together with 'mvn install' or 'mvn deploy' will cause that **instrumented** versions of your JARs will be installed. Unless this is a desired action,